# Translate SharpKit's JsObject into TypeScript

Tags: c#, javascript, typescript

I wonder how to translate `SharpKit.JavaScript.JsObject` into `TypeScript` in the best way.

If I have:

```
JsObject<string, bool> vars = new JsObject<string, bool>();
```

I translate it as:

```
var vars: { [key: string]: bool; } = {};
```

But I'm confused when I have these:

```
JsObject<string> vars = new JsObject<string>();
```

and:

```
JsObject vars = new JsObject();
```

Can anyone help me, please?

**[edit]**
I guess that

```
JsObject<string> vars = new JsObject<string>();
```

is just???

```
var vars: { [key: string]: Object; } = {};
```

Comment: For the time being, there are no generics in TypeScript, so any 'translation' of structures that use generics is going to be an approximation at best.

Comment: Could you tell me how such an approximation should look like?

Comment: No - as I've mentioned in answers to your other questions, I don't think trying to translate structures from one language to another is a very useful exercise. IM**H**O you would be better off defining the requirements of your application, then, thinking (only) of TS/JS, seeing how those requirements can best be met in code, without reference to how they might be met in C#, or PHP, or any other language.

Comment: It's for my job, they order, I do what they want, don't blame me that this looks like it looks like:(

Comment: I tried to emphasize the **Humble** in IMHO because in the end it's up to you - I just don't think there can be a correct answer to a question that tries to translate between two fundamentally different languages. Good luck with it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var vars: { [key: string]: Object; } = {};`

Unless you intend to force a cast during any access of a member of this object, this code should probably be:

`var vars: { [key: string]: any; } = {};`

which is really just another way of saying

`var vars = {};`